# Extract nodes between two nodes from xml

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an xml file:

```
<root>
<!-- all other kinds of xml elements including possibly other h1 -->

<dl> some text
  <dt>
    other text
  </dt>
</dl>
<!-- all other kinds of xml elements including possibly other h1 -->

<h1>
  <a>starting here</a>
</h1>

<dl>foo
  <dt>
    bar
  </dt>
</dl>
<dl>foo
  <dt>
    bar
  </dt>
</dl>

<!-- Many elements but all of them are dl -->

<dl>foo
  <dt>
    bar
  </dt>
</dl>
<dl>foo
  <dt>
    bar
  </dt>
</dl>

<h1>
  <a>Ending here</a>
</h1>

<!-- all other kinds of xml elements including possibly other h1 -->
<dl>foo
  <dt>
    bar
  </dt>
</dl>
<!-- all other kinds of xml elements including possibly other h1 -->

</root>
```

Now I'd like to select the `<dl>` node (with its children) between the `<h1>` tags.

I have tried various combinations of `following`, `following-sibling` but have had no success.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Should a group of `dl` elements be *immediately* preceded and *immediately* followed by `h1`, or can their immediately-preceding (following) sibling be some other type of element?

Comment: Thanks, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following XPath 1.0 expression to find the `<dl>` node between the `<h1>` tags:

```
//dl[preceding-sibling::*[1] = preceding-sibling::h1[1] and following-sibling::*[1] = following-sibling::h1[1]]
```

This will find the `<dl>` tags where the immediately preceding sibling is a `<h1>` tag, and the immediately following sibling is also a `<h1>` tag.

Depending on the requirement, it could be simplified to:

```
//dl[preceding-sibling::h1 and following-sibling::h1]
```

Which would just find all `<dl>` tags that have a `<h1>` tag somewhere before or after it.

Note that your XML would need to include a root element for it to be valid, and you generally can't execute XPath expressions on invalid XML.

Answer (score 0):

Select all dl tags after `h1` which have `h1` ahead

```
//h1/following-sibling::dl[following-sibling::h1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Both previous answers are right for the given example with two `h1` tags.
But would not work if the input is a little bit more complex e.g. with three or four `h1` tags.

If so, you can follow this excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3836240/2115381).

Here's an adaption to get the `dl` tags between first and second `h1` tag

```
 //h1[1]/following-sibling::dl
      [count(.|//h1[2]/preceding-sibling::dl) = count(//h1[2]/preceding-sibling::dl)  ]
```

Comment: hr_117, Re: "*Both previous answers are right *" -- Unfortunately, SO displays the answers in seemingly random order, and my answer, written 2 days after your answer happens to be displayed as "previous" to yours. There is no way you knew two days ago what I would answer today. Obviously, some edit is needed in order to fix this, isn't it? :)

Answer (score 0):

Because the sequence of adjacent `dl` elements must be immediately preceded and followed by `h1` siblings, one expression that selects all such sequences of `dl` elements is:

```
/*/dl[preceding-sibling::*[not(self::dl)][1][self::h1]
    and
      following-sibling::*[not(self::dl)][1][self::h1]
      ]
```

You can find all `h1` elements each of which immediately precedes such wanted adjacent sequence of `dl`s with this expression:

```
/*/h1[following-sibling::*[1][self::dl]
    and
      following-sibling::*[not(self::dl)][1][self::h1]
     ]
```

You can find all `h1` elements each of which immediately follows such wanted adjacent sequence of `dl`s with this expression:

```
/*/h1[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::dl]
    and
      preceding-sibling::*[not(self::dl)][1][self::h1]
     ]
```

---

**Finally, here is an XSLT-based verification**

This transformation just evaluates the expressions for finding all wanted sequences of `dl`s and copies them to the output.

It also evaluates the expressions that select the starting and ending `h1`s and also outputs the results.

Finally, for each pair of (starting `h1`, ending `h1`) it evaluates an XPath expression that selects all `dl`s in this particular group and outputs the results.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="
    /*/dl[preceding-sibling::*[not(self::dl)][1][self::h1]
        and
          following-sibling::*[not(self::dl)][1][self::h1]
         ]"/>
========================
<xsl:variable name="vStartingH1s" select=
 "/*/h1[following-sibling::*[1][self::dl]
       and
        following-sibling::*[not(self::dl)][1][self::h1]
        ]"/>

    <xsl:copy-of select="$vStartingH1s"/>
========================
    <xsl:variable name="vEndingH1s" select=
    "/*/h1[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::dl]
          and
           preceding-sibling::*[not(self::dl)][1][self::h1]
           ]"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$vEndingH1s"/>
========================
    <xsl:for-each select="$vStartingH1s">
      <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>
      <xsl:value-of select=
          "concat(&#xA;'========== Group ', $vPos, ' ==========&#xA;')"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select=
      "following-sibling::*
            [count(.| $vEndingH1s[position()=$vPos]/preceding-sibling::*)
            =
             count($vEndingH1s[position()=$vPos]/preceding-sibling::*)
            ]"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (the provided one, expanded to contain two groups of wanted `dl`s):

```
<root>
    <!-- all other kinds of xml elements including possibly other h1 -->
    <a/>
    <h1/>
    <dl> some text
        <dt>
        other text
        </dt>
    </dl>
    <!-- all other kinds of xml elements including possibly other h1 -->
    <b/>
    <h1/>
    <h1>
        <a>starting here</a>
    </h1>
    <dl>foo
        <dt>
        bar
        </dt>
    </dl>
    <dl>foo
        <dt>
        bar
        </dt>
    </dl>
    <!-- Many elements but all of them are dl -->
    <dl>foo
        <dt>
        bar
        </dt>
    </dl>
    <dl>foo
        <dt>
        bar
        </dt>
    </dl>
    <h1>
        <a>Ending here</a>
    </h1>
    <h1/>
    <c/>
    <h1/>
    <!-- all other kinds of xml elements including possibly other h1 -->
    <p/>
    <dl>foo
        <dt>
        bar
        </dt>
    </dl>
    <!-- all other kinds of xml elements including possibly other h1 -->
    <h1/>
    <d/>
    <h1>
        <a>starting here</a>
    </h1>
    <dl>foo
        <dt>
        bar
        </dt>
    </dl>
    <dl>foo
        <dt>
        bar
        </dt>
    </dl>
    <h1>
        <a>Ending here</a>
    </h1>
    <e/>
    <h1/>
<f/>
```

**the wanted, correct results are produced:**

```
<dl>foo
        <dt>
        bar
        </dt>

</dl>
<dl>foo
        <dt>
        bar
        </dt>

</dl>
<dl>foo
        <dt>
        bar
        </dt>

</dl>
<dl>foo
        <dt>
        bar
        </dt>

</dl>
<dl>foo
        <dt>
        bar
        </dt>

</dl>
<dl>foo
        <dt>
        bar
        </dt>

</dl>
========================
<h1>

   <a>starting here</a>

</h1>
<h1>

   <a>starting here</a>

</h1>
========================
    <h1>

   <a>Ending here</a>

</h1>
<h1>

   <a>Ending here</a>

</h1>
========================
    ========== Group 1 ==========
<dl>foo
        <dt>
        bar
        </dt>

</dl>
<dl>foo
        <dt>
        bar
        </dt>

</dl>
<dl>foo
        <dt>
        bar
        </dt>

</dl>
<dl>foo
        <dt>
        bar
        </dt>

</dl>========== Group 2 ==========
<dl>foo
        <dt>
        bar
        </dt>

</dl>
<dl>foo
        <dt>
        bar
        </dt>

</dl>
```