# C# HTMLAGILITYPACK scrape data between two tags

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Using [Html Agility Pack](https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack), I have to scrape the innerText from all //dd tags which are set between //h2 tags (in this case between h2 tags named "Applicant" and "Agent").  How can this be done?

The following is just a piece of HTML code from which I have to scrape data:

```
<!-- Applicants section  -->

    <h2 class="GridTitle">Applicant</h2>
    
        
            <h3 class="DataTitle">1</h3>
        
        <dl class="Grid LeftCol">
            <dt>Name:</dt>
            <dd>Some name here</dd>
            <dt>Legal Form:</dt>
            <dd></dd>              
            <dt>From:</dt>
            <dd>06/08/2020</dd>
        </dl>
        <dl class="Grid RightCol">
            <dt>Address:</dt>
            <dd>Some address here</dd>
            <dt>To:</dt>
            <dd></dd>
        </dl>
    
        
            <h3 class="DataTitle">2</h3>
        
        <dl class="Grid LeftCol">
            <dt>Name:</dt>
            <dd>Some name here1</dd>
            <dt>Legal Form:</dt>
            <dd></dd>              
            <dt>From:</dt>
            <dd>04/08/2010</dd>
        </dl>
        <dl class="Grid RightCol">
            <dt>Address:</dt>
            <dd>Some address here1</dd>
            <dt>To:</dt>
            <dd>06/08/2020</dd>
        </dl>
    



<!-- Agents section  -->

    <h2 class="GridTitle">Agent</h2>
```

This is something I have tried, but it takes first //dd above //h2(Agent)

```
var h2Tags = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h2[text() = 'Applicant']");
var h2Tags1 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h2[text() = 'Agent']");
var lineNum = h2Tags[0].Line;
var lineNum1 = h2Tags1[0].Line;
var Applicants = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//dd").Where(x => x.Line > lineNum).Where(x => x.Line < lineNum1);

foreach (HtmlNode g in Applicants)
{
      TMOwner = g.InnerText;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this entirely with XPath queries as follows.  You already have XPath queries to select your start and end h2 nodes.  Then you can select all `dd` nodes between pairs of them as follows:

```
var startnode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//h2[text() = 'Applicant']"); // Select the start node.
// TODO: Handle the case where startnode is null/missing here.

var endnode = startnode.SelectSingleNode("./following::h2");                     // And select the following end node using whatever criteria you need.
// TODO: Handle the case where endnode is null/missing here.

var followingXPath = $"./following::dd";                                         // Select nodes following the current node, which will be startnode
var precedingXPath = $"{endnode.XPath}/preceding::dd";                           // Select nodes preceding the end node explicitly.
var intersectedXPath = $"{followingXPath}[count(. | {precedingXPath}) = count({precedingXPath})]";

var query = startnode.SelectNodes(intersectedXPath);

var innerTexts = query.Select(n => n.InnerText).ToList();
```

Or, you could combine a simpler XPath query with a Linq [`TakeWhile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile?view=net-5.0) like so:

```
var startnode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//h2[text() = 'Applicant']"); // Select the start node.
var endnode = startnode.SelectSingleNode("./following::h2");                     // And select the following end node using whatever criteria you need.

var query = startnode.SelectNodes("./following::node()") // Select all nodes following startnode
    .TakeWhile(n => n != endnode)                        // Until endnode is reached
    .Where(n => n.Name == "dd");                         // With name "dd".
```

Notes:

- `/following::dd`, `./following::h2` and `/preceding::dd` are examples of [axes](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#axes) of [location steps](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#section-Location-Steps).  The `following` axis selects nodes in the same document as the context node that are after the context node in document order, while the `preceding` axis selects nodes in the same document as the context node that are before the context node in document order.

  If you wanted to select the next following `<h2>` node with a specific text value, say "Agent", you could do:

  ```
  var endnode = startnode.SelectSingleNode("./following::h2[text() = 'Agent']");
  ```
- The formula for `intersectedXPath` is taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3836240/3744182) by [Dimitre Novatchev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36305/dimitre-novatchev/3744182) to *[How would you find all nodes between two H3's using XPATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3835601/3744182)*.  The situation there is similar, however your question does not constrain the elements to be selected to be siblings.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xZAotx) for XPath; [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nGqwZc) for XPath + LINQ; and [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1KHCI0) for `https://bpp.economie.fgov.be/fo-eregister-view/search/details/721770937_EPV/0/0/1/10/0/0/0/null/null?locale=en`.

Comment: I tried to implement your code, but when I debug it says `[Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0501 'Program.Zip<TFirst, TSecond>(IEnumerable<TFirst>, IEnumerable<TSecond>)' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial].`  I also tried to avoid Zipping and looping thru the h2 nodes, adding manualy XPath to `[startXPath]` and `[endXPath]`, but then I have problem in this line  `var innerTexts = query.Select(n => n.InnerText).ToList();` with explanation : 'Value cannot be null.'

Comment: @TomislavBoberic - 1) what version of .Net (and HTML Agility Pack) are you using?  Possibly that overload of `Zip` does not exist in your version.  2) `var innerTexts = query.Select(n => n.InnerText).ToList();` -- please share a [mcve], specifically HTML that reproduces the problem.  I did test with the HTML in your question, see the demo fiddles.

Comment: @TomislavBoberic - I modified the answer + fiddles to avoid use of `.Zip()` entirely.

Comment: this is the [example](https://bpp.economie.fgov.be/fo-eregister-view/search/details/721770937_EPV/0/0/1/10/0/0/0/null/null?locale=en) of URL from which I have to scrape data. Now I have problem with `var endnode = h2nodes[i + 1];` as it says "index was out of range. must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."

Comment: @TomislavBoberic - If the index was out of range then you have an odd number of  `<h2>` nodes.  So you need to define what you want to in such a case.  Will look at the URL.

Comment: @TomislavBoberic - the web page at `"https://bpp.economie.fgov.be/fo-eregister-view/search/details/721770937_EPV/0/0/1/10/0/0/0/null/null?locale=en` is missing the closing `<h2 class=""GridTitle"">Agent</h2>` node, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/qNF6Z3.  I updated the code to not throw an exception in such a case, but what do you actually want to do then?

Comment: sometimes after Applicant informations goes Inventors, sometimes Agents it depends of the number of patent you are searching for

Comment: That page doesn't have an `Inventors` tag, it has `Inventor`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/GRf4rb.  Is what you really want **the next `<h2>` tag after "Applicant"**?

Comment: If you want to select between the h2 Applicant node and the next h2 node, you can set `var endnode = startnode.SelectSingleNode("./following::h2");`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/AKV1c2.  If that's what you want I can update the answer (and question).

Comment: In this case I need all `<dd>` between `Applicant` and `Inventor`

Comment: OK, but is it always `Inventor` or is it sometimes `Inventors`?  Is there any chance there is an h2 tag between your start and end tags and you want to scrape contents on both sides of that middle tag?

Comment: No it's always `Inventor`. Your code is good now, I think I got the point.